# MSSQL count total time between many entries and exitis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to ask you for help on how to count the total time spent between many entries and exits. The example table looks as follows (for one user):

```
Date_Time               | Event        | User
------------------------|--------------|---------
2016-08-01 09:19:11.000 | Reader entry | John D.
2016-08-01 10:00:56.997 | Reader exit  | John D.
2016-08-01 10:09:24.000 | Reader entry | John D.
2016-08-01 11:14:12.000 | Reader exit  | John D.
2016-08-01 12:41:15.997 | Reader entry | John D.
2016-08-01 12:45:28.000 | Reader exit  | John D.
2016-08-01 12:47:23.000 | Reader entry | John D.
2016-08-01 13:37:06.997 | Reader exit  | John D.
2016-08-01 13:38:54.997 | Reader entry | John D.
2016-08-01 13:43:01.000 | Reader exit  | John D.
```

I would like to count the total time spent from entry to exit in a given day for a given person. In the above example, for John D., it will be in total 02:40:30.

I use MSSQL 2012.

Thank you for your help in advance,
Pawel

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `LAG` window function

```
    select [user], sum(datediff(s,prev_date_time,date_time)) as seconds
      from 
       (select [user], date_time, Event,
              lag(Date_time) over (partition by [user] order by Date_time) as prev_date_time,
              lag(Event) over (partition by [user] order by Date_time) as prev_event
          from myTable) as t
     where Event = 'Reader exit'
       and prev_event = 'Reader entry'
   group by [user];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
user    seconds
John D. 9876
```

That's actually 2:44:36, I don't know how you got 02:40:30.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Mark it as answered if you don't mind.